# Dissimilarity vs Difference - What is the correct usage?

Tags: word-choice

I am confused as to the appropriate use of *dissimilarity* when the word *difference* means practically the exact same thing.

Are there any unique cases when *dissimilarity* is a preferred term over the other, or is it down to the author's personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Difference' has a greater range of meanings than 'dissimilarity'. It can refer both to a *difference between one entity and another* and to a *different state or condition existing in the same entity*, whereas the property of dissimilarity requires a comparison between *two or more separate entities*.

Compare, for instance:

> 1) There's a difference in the way you are behaving today
>
> 2) *There's a dissimilarity in the way you are behaving today
>
> 3) There's a difference in the behaviour of the two boys
>
> 4) There's a dissimilarity in the behaviour of the two boys

Variant 2) would implicitly invite the question "Dissimilarity to what?", whereas the comparison in 1) self-evidently relates back to the object of the speaker's observation.

Where two different entities are being compared (as in 3) and 4)), both 'difference' and 'dissimilarity' can be used.